# javascript method replace is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, replace

My app  read DOM object's attribute value. I want this value to be swapped with some new texts and put back to attribute. The original value is:

```
"position: absolute; background-image: url(\"http://dealer.raymarine.com/Views/Public/ShowImage.ashx?partno=M81203&view=thumb\")";
```

but when it should be updated with JS replace method, but nothing is changed, why?

Updating JS code:

```
var styleValue = ui.helper[0].getAttribute("style");
styleValue.replace("raymarine", "XXX");
styleValue.replace("ShowImage", "ShowImageSystemCreator");
styleValue.replace("view=thumb", "view=png");
ui.helper[0].setAttribute("style", styleValue);
console.log("draggable after text swap: " + styleValue);
```

Comment: `replace` doesn't update the string, it need to be assigned to the same variable `styleValue = styleValue.replace("raymarine", "XXX");`

Comment: Remember: strings are immutable. You can't alter them, you can only produce new ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not saving the value anywhere!

```
styleValue = styleValue.replace("raymarine", "XXX");
styleValue = styleValue.replace("ShowImage", "ShowImageSystemCreator");
styleValue = styleValue.replace("view=thumb", "view=png");
```

Make it a one-liner if you want by stringing `replace`s:

```
styleValue = styleValue.replace("raymarine", "XXX").replace("ShowImage", "ShowImageSystemCreator").replace("view=thumb", "view=png");
```